# How to align 3 items responsively next to each other in ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive

does anyone know how to align three items next to each other in ReactJS? Also it should be responsive. Here is my current code:

```
const EntrySection = () => {
  return (
    <section className='entry-section'>
        <div className='entry-wrapper'>
            <EntryCard {...cardData} className='card' />
            <EntryCard {...cardData} className='card' />
            <EntryCard {...cardData} className='card' />
            <EntryCard {...cardData} className='card' />
            <EntryCard {...cardData} className='card' />
            <EntryCard {...cardData} className='card' />
        </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default EntrySection
```

```scss
@import '/src/Variables.scss';

.entry-section {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    background: $gray-3;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 300px;

    .entry-wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 50px 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;

        .card {
            flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
        }
    }
}
```

Sadly with this code every card is stacked over each other.
Thank you for helping! :)

Comment: `flex` should be `1`, not whatever that `0 0 33.33%` is.

Comment: still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex and gap,
I dont know if this is what you want to achieve but here is an example:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEdPU.png)

```
.entry-section {
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.entry-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 9px;
}

.card {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi based on my understanding of your case, you maybe want to try implement a grid.

with the combination of auto-fill/auto-fit, and with minmax().

like in this article (around the bottom part):
https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/node-path-intermediate-html-and-css-advanced-grid-properties

i hope this info can get you somewhere to your desire output.

Edit:
im sry i did'nt put any code before, now i will try to recreate your design with this code below.

```css
.entry-section {
    height: 500px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: rgb(228, 255, 222);
}
.entry-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px,1fr));
    background: rgb(164, 238, 183);
}
.card {
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background: rgb(245, 245, 245);
    background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/45201/kitty-cat-kitten-pet-45201.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500') no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<section class='entry-section'>
        <div class='entry-wrapper'>
            <div class='card'>
                card
            </div>
            <div class='card'>
                card
            </div>
            <div class='card'>
                card
            </div>
            <div class='card'>
                card
            </div>
            <div class='card'>
                card
            </div>
            <div class='card'>
                card
            </div>
            <div class='card'>
                card
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </section>
```

Because you want an exact 3 images to show, but also responsively
i tried to make it with grid.

first i make sure the entry-section class to have a maximum of 1000px. if you resize your screen then you will get less than 1000px.

after that i make a grid with grid-template-columns with repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px,1fr) basicly this css code will make a cell of 300px width minimum, and take any available space if available.

so if your screen width is let say 700px, the grid will make 2 card with around 300px width.

if your screen witdh is let say 400 px, then the grid will make 1 card with around 300px of width.

i hope this can help you with your project

Comment: Does not really work how it should :(
https://prnt.sc/X7c7Qa5UDCk8